# searching for string with php on mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently doing a string search on a mysql column for generating seo friendly urls. I am searching duplicates with this:

```
SELECT * FROM url WHERE slug LIKE '%' . $testString . '%'
```

so if in the column I have :

```
about-company
about-company-1
```

then the next would be

```
about-company-2
```

but my problem is that is $testString have the value of 'about co' that would then made the 3 other links a valid hence will generate

```
about-co-3
```

So how could I check to make sure about co is not the same as about company?

thanks

Comment: Can you provide the relevant PHP code for your comparison?

Comment: can you add clarity to the last third of what you wrote. Confusing to me at least.

Comment: Please have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - Minimal, Complete and Verified Example - for guidance on how to ask a good questions on stackoverflow that makes it both easy and likely for us to help you.